# iPod won't mount when plugged in

Tags: windows, mac, ipod

I have a windows formatted iPod with disk access enabled.  Occasionally, my USB connection flakes out.  This used to happen more often when I connected via USB hub, so I no longer do this.  However, when this happens, I can't seem to mount my iPod -- to get it to show up in iTunes or even in the Finder.  Typically, this happens when I am on my Mac, although I'm pretty sure I've had this same problem on Windows.

I've tried:

- Rebooting my iPod
- Unplugging and plugging back in my iPod
- Rebooting my computer

None of these things work.  Fortunately, I eventually figured out that if I plug it in to the other OS, than the problem reverts.  In other words, if the problem happened while connected to my Mac, if I then plug my iPod in to Windows, things get better.  Likewise, if the problem happened while connected to Windows, if I then connect to my Mac it gets better.

This seems odd, and not a general solution for typical people who don't have multiple PC's with differing OS's.  Is there a better way to fix it?

Details:

- 160 GB
- version 1.1.2 PC

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend re-installing iTunes on both systems. If that doesn't fix it, you can try enabling detection actions such as opening the folder to browse the device when windows recognizes it as a device. You can do this to just see if your OS is even recognizing the fact that your iPod is connected.

Another thing to try, is to use another USB-iPod cable. Your cable might be defective.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try restoring the ipod to its factory settings.  Refreshing the firmware might solve the  problem since it seems like it's independent of the two operating systems.

Comment: I use the iPod as an external storage drive.  Would refreshing the firmware would case me to lose this data?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.  It will reset the ipod to the same state you got it in.